# React js fetch api show different behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I make a server call using **fetch API** except one post request all another post/get request hit on the exactly/desire server URL, but the one post requests hit on the localhost server.

service class code and base URL for the post request is the same as others.

> service.js:56 POST http://localhost:3000/.... 500 (Internal Server Error)

Code:

```js
function save(workflow) {
    const token = authenticationGenerator.generateAuthenticationToken(localStorage.getItem('username'),
        localStorage.getItem('password'));

    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': token },
        body: JSON.stringify(workflow)
    };
    return fetch('/workflow', requestOptions)
        .then(handleResponse).then(workflowData => {
            return workflowData;
        });
}
```

... hit on localhost ...

```js
function save(phase) {
    const token = authenticationGenerator.generateAuthenticationToken(localStorage.getItem('username'),
        localStorage.getItem('password'));
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': token },
        body: JSON.stringify(phase)
    };
    return fetch('/phases', requestOptions)
        .then(handleResponse).then(phaseData => {
            return phaseData;
        });
}
```

...package.json ...

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"proxy": "http://url../v1",
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
},
```

Comment: If you're testing on a device, make sure you're on the same WiFi

Comment: Did you try `postman` to make sure your `/phases` end point is working perfectly? Code 500 is something side of server

Comment: Yes, on postman it working perfectly.  Click here: https://pasteboard.co/IFHBlfk.png

Answer (score 0):

Do you have correct routing for `/phases` location at the server end?

Comment: Those functions have same name and same amount of parameters, are you sure they don't get mixed up in the calling end? I mean, how do you know which one gets called?

Comment: URL endpoint and requestionOption method are different ... baseurl/phase and baseurl/workflow